# Concatenating pointclouds gets very slow

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I have implemented an algorithm that uses ransac to align pointclouds obtained by consecutive scenes and add them to a pointcloud representing the map called total_cloud using the pcl concatenate function. So total_cloud starts empty and then gradually grows as more pointclouds are aligned and added.

My question is why does it get slower and slower as the map gets bigger? I am not using total_cloud in any other computation so it is not part of my computation, only adding the new aligned pointcloud to it. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? From my understanding, total_cloud is a just a chunk of memory that is growing dynamically, and is not part of any computation.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Best regards,
Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81331/concatenating-pointclouds-gets-very-slow/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dynamically growing memory is very expensive as it will require reallocating and copying data. It's usually more expensive than operating on the data.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like also to remind you that the more you add points, the more you have points. Which means that the heavier will your total_cloud will become.

You should add two steps :

1. remove outliers (like described in pcl [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php#statistical-outlier-removal) or [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/remove_outliers.php#remove-outliers) )
2. downsample the total_cloud (like described in pcl [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php#voxelgrid)

Have a good day ! Keep us updated :-)

Stéphane

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1